# Plot of Fourier series involving prime

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, graphing-functions, python

So, I was playing with Fourier series just for fun and got a weird idea.

I'm sure that someone have think of this series before 
$f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {{\frac {(-1)^n} {p_n}}\sin(p_nx)}$ 
Where $p_n$ is the n-th prime number 
This is the plot involving first 20 prime numbers using desmos.

[image]

I have 2 questions regarding this series.

1. Is this plot smooth and/or analytics in the limit?
2. Does anyone know how to plot this function?

I try using python, but couldn't really figure out how to do it.

Comment: I think that what you plotted is $$f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} {p_n}}\sin(p_nx)}$$ Why not to rescale the plot to make it nicer (say $y$ values between $-1.2$ and $1.2$). ?$ Interesting problem

Comment: I tried with the first $10,000$ first prime numbers. It does not change much (as we can expect).

Comment: What could be interesting would be remove the noise from the signal.  Have a look at https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-filter-noise-with-a-low-pass-filter-python-885223e5e9b7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the plot, use the following input in Wolfram Alpha

`Plot[Sum[((-1)^(1 + n)*Sin[x*Prime[n]])/Prime[n], {n, 1, p}],{x,-2Pi,2Pi}]`

Give $p$ the value you want

Comment: Thank you for the code. After seeing more terms, I even more curious whether the function is analytics, or maybe its a fractal